# TCPDF - DIV is showing extra space before and after

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am converting a long form in pdf using TCPDF. My structure of html is like this:

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> ..one more table ..</div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But in output of PDF, there is some extra space (about 20px) before and after div. When  I remove that `<div>` it looks perfect. But I cant remove that. I am unable to figure out the solution.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try `<div style="page-break-inside: avoid; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">`

Comment: TCPDF ignores margin and padding for divs :(

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but look at the [setHtmlVSpace](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a71cec8b4c54a78429640e4767648e73e) class.

Comment: $tagvs = array('p' => array(0 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0), 1 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0)));
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);

Answer (score 6):

The space inside your block `<td>` is interpreted.
You can write your code like this to remove the space :

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
  <tr>
      <td><div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> ..one more table ..</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you use a templating language as Twig or Smarty, there are some solutions to put arround your code :
Twig : `{% spaceless %}` https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html
Smarty : `{strip}` http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/fr/language.function.strip.tpl

Answer (score 4):

To set the vertical spaces for HTML tags, in this case `div` use:

```
$tagvs = {'div' => [{'h' => 0, 'n' => 0}, {'h' => 0, 'n' => 0}]}
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
```

> `$tagvs`: Array of tags and relative vertical spaces.
>
> [{'h' => 0, 'n' => 0}, {'h' => 0, 'n' => 0}]: First for opening tag
> 'div', Second for closing tag '/div'.
>
> 'h' : Vertical space unit
>
> 'n' : Number spaces to add